# Anychart does not resize on window resize

Tags: angularjs, anychart

I recently switched my AngularJS application to be build with Webpack. Everything works fine, except all my charts using `anychart` do not resize when the window resize, as they used to before I migrated to Webpack (I was using the asset pipeline from Rails before).

What could be the reason? how does anychart actually resize? I could not find anything from the official docs or api.

Before I was using this to load anychart:

```
//= require anychart/dist/js/anychart-bundle.min
//= require anychart/dist/js/anychart-ui.min
```

Now with Webpack:

```
import anychart from 'anychart';
import 'anychart/dist/js/anychart-ui.min';
```

Edit 1:
The angularjs version used is `1.6.9` and anychart is `8.1.0`

Comment: Thank you for this report! But we need some additional details to investigate this issue. Can you provide us information about AngularJS version and anychart version?

Comment: @AnyChartSupport edited with versions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have prepared a dev preview with the fix for it. Please, try install dev preview version of anychart module.

```
npm install -g anychart@8.2.0-preview-0103
```

And please, let us know about the result.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. When should version `8.2.0` be rolled out? thanks

Comment: Great! The release of 8.2.0 version is scheduled for the second half of March 2018